# Не работает автообновление browsersync

Tags: node.js, browsersync

Установил nodejs и пытаюсь сделать автообновление через browsersync. Но оно не работает. В чём причина?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Может Browser-sync не понимает кирилицу в пути.

Comment: Да. Дело было в кириллице

Comment: У меня такая же проблема, в смысле не понимает кириллицу как это исправить?